# Custom weighted IoU loss for binary semantic segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation, loss-function

I would like to ask if my implementation of the weighted IoU loss is correct. Given satellite images, I am trying to segment road and foreground pixels.

```
    def compute_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        
        '''Implementation code to calculate weighted IoU loss for U-Net model. 
        
        Args:
            y_true: tensor of shape (batch_size, 400, 400, 1), containing pixel values of groundtruth image
            y_pred: tensor of shape (batch_size, 400, 400, 1), containing pixel values of prediction from model

        Returns:
            loss
        '''        
        
        scores = []
        class_weights = [self.foreground_weight, self.road_weight]
        
        for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
            
            y_true_sample = tf.reshape(y_true[i], [-1])
            y_pred_sample = tf.reshape(y_pred[i], [-1])
            
            intersection = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(y_true_sample, tf.float32)*tf.cast(y_pred_sample, tf.float32))
            smoothing = 1
            iou = (intersection + smoothing)/ (tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(y_true_sample, tf.float32)) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(y_pred_sample, tf.float32)) - intersection + smoothing)
            
            weighted_iou = tf.reduce_sum((1. - iou)*class_weights)
            scores.append(weighted_iou)
            
        scores = tf.convert_to_tensor(scores, dtype = tf.float32)
        return tf.reduce_mean(scores)
```

Here, I am passing in batch sizes of 8. The final layer of my U-Net model is a 1x1 convolution layer which is then passed through a sigmoid activation. This results in an output shape of (batch_size, height, width, 1) where each pixel value represents the probability of the pixel belonging to the class labelled as 1.

However, when I am training my model, the train loss seems to stagnate after a few epochs.

I tried experimenting with different learning rate but the loss either gets stuck at a value or the model is not able to learn when the learning rate is too slow.

Note: Class weights are added because the proportion of foreground pixels to road pixels is 9:1.

Is my implementation correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss

class WeightedIoULoss(Loss):
    def __init__(self, weight_background=1.0, weight_foreground=1.0, epsilon=1e-7, **kwargs):
        super(WeightedIoULoss, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.weight_background = weight_background
        self.weight_foreground = weight_foreground
        self.epsilon = epsilon

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred)
        union = tf.reduce_sum(y_true + y_pred - y_true * y_pred)

        iou = (intersection + self.epsilon) / (union + self.epsilon)

        # Calculate the weighted IoU loss
        weighted_loss = -tf.math.log(iou) * (self.weight_background * (1 - y_true) + self.weight_foreground * y_true)

        return weighted_loss

# Example usage
loss = WeightedIoULoss(weight_background=0.5, weight_foreground=1.5)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Could you explain ```weighted_loss = -tf.math.log(iou) * (self.weight_background * (1 - y_true) + self.weight_foreground * y_true)```? I don't really understand this part of your solution.